# Techniques Modifying Cells M8.0

Tags: front-end, notebooks, cells, version-8

What techniques are there for modifying/organizing/selecting/deleting cells?  I understand Mathematica 9.0 has a [`Cells`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Cells.html) function but what techniques exist in Mathematica 8.0?  The documentation for effectively using and modifying `Cell`s seems quite limited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Techniques for modifying cells in Mathematica 8.0**

Deletes all output `Cells`

```
FrontEndExecute[{
  FrontEnd`NotebookFind[nb, "Output", All, CellStyle, AutoScroll -> False], 
  FrontEnd`FrontEndToken["Clear"]
}];
```

Sets all `Cells` background to **Green**.

```
ModifyCells@Function[
  CurrentValue[#, Background] = Green;
]
```

retrieve a list of `Cells`

```
NotebookGet[][[1]]
```

Find cell based on `CellTags`

```
CellPrint[TextCell["abcd", "Text", CellTags -> "tag"]]
> abcd 
NotebookLocate["tag"]; NotebookRead[EvaluationNotebook[]]
> Cell["abcd", "Text", GeneratedCell -> True, CellAutoOverwrite -> True,CellTags -> "tag"]
```

Set `TaggingRules` for `Notebook`

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[],TaggingRules -> "InputFieldState" -> "initial string"]
```

Get `TaggingRules` for `Notebook`

```
Options[EvaluationNotebook[]], TaggingRules]
CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], TaggingRules]
```

another way to retrieve list of `Cells`

```
NotebookTools`NotebookScan[InputNotebook[], Function[
   InputForm[NotebookRead[InputNotebook[]]]
   ]];
```

And the needed functions to get the examples to work:

```
ModifyCells[fun_] := (
  i = 0;
  length = Length[NotebookGet[EvaluationNotebook[]][[1]]] + 1;
  NotebookTools`NotebookScan[InputNotebook[], (
     If[i < length,
      fun[NotebookSelection[#], i++];,
      Null
      ]
     ) &
   ];
  i
  )
```

Will also retrieve a list of `Cells`

```
Cells[nb_] := (
  SelectionMove[nb, All, Notebook];
  content = NotebookRead[nb];
  SelectionMove[nb, All, Cell];
  content
  )

Cells[EvaluationNotebook[]]
```

Comment: But `Cells` in v9 returns completely different objects as in v8 with your `Cells` function, so I guess usage further on will differ considerably too.

Comment: I agree with @SjoerdC.deVries. If you want the list of cells you could also do `First@NotebookGet`

Comment: @Rojo I see what you mean how would I make the following code work `Map[(SetOptions[#, Background -> Green]) &, First[NotebookGet[]]]`  Basically loop through all the cells in Mathematica 8.0 and set the background green.

Comment: An option could be =-``NotebookTools`NotebookScan[InputNotebook[], 
 nb \[Function] 
  CurrentValue[NotebookSelection[nb], Background] = Green]``

Comment: The `NotebookScan` function is very similar to your function, but it allows you to do something else while the cell is selected (instead of your `NotebookRead`). In this case, setting the background of the current selection to green

Comment: I haven't seen the \\[Function] operator before, therefore I kinda prefer `NotebookTools\`NotebookScan[InputNotebook[], Function[CurrentValue[NotebookSelection[#], Background] =Green;]]`